# Zend Server CE (Windows) Newbie Question: Created a New Project But Not Sure Where to Place It!

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server-ce

I am a newbie to the Zend Framework. I just finished installing Zend Server CE for Windows. Using the command line tool, I browsed to the desktop and did:
    zf create project example

I see that an empty directory structure has been created on the desktop called "example". How can I have this example application run in my browser? Currently, when I point my browser to:
    http://localhost:10081/ZendServer/

...I see the admin interface. I thought I should move the newly-created "example" folder somewhere inside the ZendServer directory, which is located at:
    C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer

No luck. Can someone please help me access this new example project so that I can at least be able to run its default index view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root (www) directory to host the code is the below path. Everything inside that folder can be read by apache

C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs

Comment: So if I place the entire "example" folder inside that directory, how can I access the index view of that project via the web browser?

Comment: In case you have configured apache to listen to port 85 let say. You must browse you project like this.                       http://localhost:85/example/public

Comment: Got it!! All I did was take out the port (or, leave in the port, which was implicitly 80). Thanks!!

Comment: Okay, so now, how do I access a new controller I created called "People"? I also created its corresponding script/view/people/people.phtml, but when I go to "http://localhost/example/public/people", it does not work!

Comment: I am not very familiar with zend framework, on how they implement MVC patterns. So have a look in zend framework it will help you out more.  [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html)